# Shopify add/remove items from cart attributes

Tags: jquery, async-await, shopify

i have problems adding/removing items from shopifys cart attributes.
Following the [documentation](https://shopify.dev/api/ajax/reference/cart#post-locale-cart-clear-js) for that i basically copied and slightly edited this code:

```
let formData = {
 'items': [{
  'id': 36110175633573,
  'quantity': 666
  }]
};

  let addAttributeResponse = fetch(window.Shopify.routes.root + 'cart/add.js', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify(formData)
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log("Add attribute to card success response: ", response);
    return response.json();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

I get within the success block an 404 Not Found Error:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why this fails? My goal is basically to remove some attributes which are added before. I have attributes which are customizations for products. But when a user adds a product to the cart, and then removes it, the attribute i added before is still there and if he buys another product i have the old (not needed) attribute inside my order.

Any tips would be great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried that code on my store and it works just fine. You can find more details about the issue in Network Tab in the developer tools in the request's response.

404 status code indicates that you are using the wrong variant id. Please make sure that you did not confuse it with product id which is different or double-check the variant id.

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot. Within the network response was an error message. But one more question, du you know if its possible to remove entrys from carts attributes block? I did not found any options inside the docs.

Comment: @SupaMario you can update the attribute with the null value and it should get removed. Example: https://gist.github.com/chrisjhoughton/893f536698e2c27cb7f5?permalink_comment_id=2575095#gistcomment-2575095